# How to protect local database files from non-admin users

Tags: mysql, security, database-security

We have a computer which has MySql installed, and it has no internet connection, so the only way to access to MySql is using that computer. The users are using a C# aplication to interact with the database, and each has their own password, so anyone that doesn't have the credentials won't be able to use the aplication. BUT, since the MySql database is installed in the same computer, the users can access the database directory and files locally, and they can take information from there.

My question is: Is there a way so that only the computer's admin user can have access to the database files, BUT hide the files from non-admin users, and force them to use the aplication?

I have tried setting a password to the files but I can't make it work, and I don't know if this is the solution

Comment: By default MySQL server service is running using built-in NETWORK account. Users are used their local accounts. So find MySQL data directory, disable inherited access rights and set access rights on it directly - full access for SYSTEM and NETWORK accounts and for Administrators group, and none for all another local groups/users.